# Illustrator - resize position but keep shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

I am looking for a simple way to resize the position of elements of a group of elements in one dimension, without resizing/distorting the individual elements.

I.e. I have a simple scatter graph (circles as points) and need to resize it in the y-domain. If i do the usual resizing, all circles will be resized in the y-domain as well.
I want to have a resized group, but "protect" some of the individual elements in the group from distortions. Is this possible?

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Effect > Convert to Shape > Ellipse` to change all of your squashed ovals to circles of arbitrary size.

Comment: This workaround (as it works only for circles/ellipses) gave me a idea which is not ideal, but works:
Transform the whole thing e.g. 50% vertical 100% horizontal, then go in on an individual path level and use the transform each and re-transform it: 200% vertical 100% horizontal.
It would of course be nice to have this as a native tool, or an easier way.

Comment: There's no native tool that I know of, but it would be easy enough to implement in a script.

Answer (score 0):

In illustrator Cc try Grouping the objects, then select the DIRECT selection tool, click on the object that you would like resized and right click - select transform from the drop down menu then select scale, then type in the percentage you would like it resized by.

Comment: This is not what I intend to do. Try it yourself: use 50% horizontal and 100% vertical. While the position will change, the individual shapes will also be distorted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that those elements are in group. For re-size you have to go in isolation mode.First press 'V' move tool by double clicking on that group you will be in isolation mode now all the elements will be separately select-able so chose the shape and re-size it on the shape dimensions panel according to your will.

Comment: But I don't see how this then changes the size of the whole graph?